# How can a planet have relatively common lethal hailstones?

Tags: planets, environment, atmosphere, weather, natural-disasters

Sometimes hailstones reach sizes that are deadly to large animals and people and livestock have been killed. This is a relatively rare occurrence on Earth of course. If I want a planet where lethal hail is a somewhat common danger for anyone trapped outside, what atmospheric conditions does the planet need to have compared to Earth, besides being cold and windy and how could that come about?

Comment: Hail is forms in up-drafts in thunderstorms. These carry the forming ice balls up to altitudes cold enough to continue adding ice. There would need to be more frequent severe thunderstorms. I'm guessing something to do with more humidity, thicker atmosphere. But tons of things will affect this. You might get somewhere by researching what locations get the most hail.

Comment: Couldn't agree more than with what @puppetsock said. Show us the research you've done, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I am curious for the next question "How do my trees survive my massive hailstorms" =)

Comment: "relatively rare occurrence" is very relative. I've had to replace 4 windscreens on my cars so far.   2 of then were parked in a garage with a corrugated iron roof. The hail punched through the roof, bending the plates apart... figure 4-6 inch (15cm) hailstones. Some places in Earth already has pretty lethal hail

Comment: A Single hailstorm in India (a long time ago, 1888), killed 246 people. ..  a SINGLE hailstorm.https://www.severe-weather.eu/global-weather/large-giant-hail-libya-mk/

Answer (score 1):

#### Just add humidity and temperature.

Basically - you need to add extra heat at ground level to create stronger updrafts. [Image source](https://www.weathermod-bg.eu/pages/obr_en.php)

[image]

Rising hot moist air helps lift moisture droplets up and down over and over inside the storm cell making the hail grow in size. The stronger the updraft, the more weight in hail it can support on subsequent cycles in the cloud to make it larger.

You'll get a temperature differential across terrain boundaries (city vs fields, land vs water, etc), across the day/night terminator line as it cycles the globe, or between terrain in cloud shadow vs direct sunlight. The stronger the difference in temperature, and the more moisture there is, the worse your hailstones.

This is one reason why "Global warming" became "Climate change" - the extra heat becomes energy added into a storm cell, resulting in a [trend of stronger and more damaging storms](https://www.adelaide.edu.au/news/news101462.html). An alternative answer to your question could be: "what climate change activists are trying to avoid here on earth".

Comment: You might provide a link to research demonstrating a trend in storm severity. Hint: There isn't one.

Comment: @puppetsock That's provably false. Just for my home city with a casual google search I can find dozens. eg http://www.bom.gov.au/state-of-the-climate/australias-changing-climate.shtml https://soe.environment.gov.au/theme/built-environment/topic/2016/increased-extreme-weather-events https://www.adelaide.edu.au/news/news101462.html Deaths from extreme weather events have about doubled between 2007 and 2020

Comment: Your link refers to deaths due to heat exposure. So it's not relevant.  Also, it refers to only two years of data, not even the intervening years of data, nor the long term trend. And then it stitches on "scenarios." So your link is misleading.